# Is a differential tensor equation still true if I raise/lower indices?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, tensors, laplacian

I'm specifically wondering about the equation

$\Box R_{abcd} = 0$

If this equation holds in some manifold, is it also true that

$\Box {R^a}_{bcd} = 0$ ?

It's not obvious to me, because contraction with the metric doesn't appear to commute with the differential operator.  Yet conceptually, it seems like all we're doing is replacing a vector with its co-vector, and if the vector has zero Laplacian then surely the co-vector does as well?

Comment: It works because $\square$ is defined from covariant derivatives and the metric is a parallel tensor, so $\square g^{ae}=0$.

Comment: You should confirm for yourself that raising an index of a tensor commutes with covariant differentiation. I recommend doing this first with 1-tensor (i.e., a 1-form) in local coordinates. And then a 2-tensor. You won't need to do anything more after that.

Comment: Thank you both for the very helpful responses!